# Date Format difference causing crash

Tags: c#, .net, datetime-format

Hi I am writing a piece of code to find the latest date among a list of dates, the problem is that the date was specified in a string. I convert it to a DateTime object using:

```
private DateTime DateRetStr(string ss)
{
    DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
    dtfi.ShortDatePattern = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DateTimeFormat"];
    dtfi.DateSeparator = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DateTimeSeperator"];
    DateTime objDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ss, dtfi);
    return objDate;
}
```

right now when i change my computer i need to change the app.config file to the correct date seperator and format else my program crashes. Is there any way to automatically update the app.config file according to the system format?

Thanks

Comment: How do you get input strings? Is this data also generated by .NET app on target machine or is the datetime format in input data always the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use `DateTime.Parse(ss)` to get a DateTime object and don't read any configs.

Comment: thank you so much, silly of me to overlook this! will accept answer in 25 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.TryParse` methods actually use system settings for date and time representation, so you should be fine without any format strings in your config if you use these methods.